# What are the Path components of $\mathbb{R^w}$ in product topology.

Tags: general-topology

$\mathbb{R^w}$ is connected in product topology but what about the path components of $\mathbb{R^w}$ in product topology?

Comment: In a product of path-connected spaces, what would be the natural candidate for a path connecting two points? Would that work? If not, how would it fail?

Comment: No that may not work...For finite product of path connected set it would be path connected but is it true for infinite product?

Comment: Yes it also works for infinite product because infinite product of continuous map is also continuous. i.e a mapping from $\mathbb{R}$  to $\mathbb{R^w}$ with all its components continuous is continuous. I am sorry .I should think before posting this question...